Does memoization skew benchmarks?
I'm writing a program that works with directed acyclic graphs and performs rewriting operations on them. Sometimes the graphs are small, sometimes they can be very large and grow as the program advances.
In the context of my program, it is common for many graphs to have sufficiently similar sub-graphs that certain operations on a graph G₂ can go through some of the same rewriting steps as for a previous (sub-)graph G₁. I'll skip the details.
To avoid recalculating similar operations several times, I optimise my program using memoization. This consists of storing the result of an operation in memory after it has been calculated, so you don't have to recalculate it later. Using this optimization seems natural to me, given the context (it's also common in functional programming, and I code with F#). In practice, this works very well and gives me a visible performance boost.
To really measure a performance gain, I need to do a benchmark. The benchmark will normally run the code I've given it several times and compile statistics and averages on that code. I see, not really surprisingly (I was kind of expecting it), that on average my memoised code executes in a very short amount of time, close to 0ms. If I remove the memoization, the execution time is obviously far from 0ms.
From this, I can conclude either that my optimisation is perfect, or that my optimisation cheats on the benchmark. The order of magnitude between the two versions (memoized and non-memoized) is significant.
My code uses an optimisation technique that, maybe, seems to skew the benchmark: what the benchmark actually measures in the long run is not the calculations on the graphs, but the speed at which a key is found in a hash table (other operations have a cost, but it is or seems to be very low compared to the more costly operations that have been memoized). Of course, my memoization isn't trivially applied to the function being benchmarked (otherwise it would just be cheating), but to certain processes in my code that I've judged to be expensive and that are called by the function I'm benchmarking or other linked process.
I'm a bit confused as to what conclusions I should draw from this, because I want to measure the performance gain of an optimisation, but this optimisation is such that the more the code advances the faster the program becomes. So my question is this: is benchmarking memoised code useful? And how should the results be interpreted? Or how do you run a benchmark for such an optimisation?

If you want to obtain some kind of a measurement or estimate of the performance gain due to memoization, perhaps you could, if possible, set up one or more scenarios (i.e. a particular graph specifically made for this purpose), where you can first do a "warmup run" that makes sure everything that can be memoized is memoized, and then you do your benchmark. You'd still have to interpret the results and figure out how to generalize them to other scenarios, but maybe you can come up with a test scenario/graph that allows you to do that.

If you trying to determine if the memoization if improving performance, you seem to have your answer.  If you are trying to determine exactly how much it improves, that's a more complicated question. "From this, I can conclude either that my optimisation is perfect, or that my optimisation cheats on the benchmark." Those aren't the only 2 options and I'm not even sure what you mean by the latter.

In general, memoization can potentially skew benchmarks because it can subtly change what's actually being tested between runs. But if what you are benchmarking is a real-world scenario and you are actually testing the benefits of memoization vs non-memoization, then it's an entirely valid benchmark and what you are seeing is the tangible benefits of memoization in a production setting.

The question I would ask is, does the number of repetitions affect the reported average? For example, if the cache is not cleared between measurements, and it takes 10 seconds on the first run and 1 second on all subsequent runs, then doing 10 runs will give an average of 1.9 seconds, 100 runs will average 1.09 seconds, and 1000 runs will average 1.009 seconds. So you get very different averages just from increasing the sample size! So you must reset the cache between runs.

Then assuming you want your average to reflect a mixture of "fresh" and "cache already initialised" usages, do multiple accesses within one run. Choose a usage pattern which reflects what you want to measure. But then each measurement should measure the time for the whole of that usage pattern, not the individual accesses made within the pattern. And the cache must be cleared between each measurement, so that the measurements are independent. This way, the average will make sense and won't just measure the number of times you performed the experiment.

@kaya3: Ah, good points, especially the second comment. Thanks :)

This sounds like you are indecisive about the overall goal of your benchmark.

Do you want to measure the speed in "production"? The speed of the program when run under "real-world conditions", when it is used for the use cases it is intended for?

Or do you want to measure just for learning purposes? To get a better understanding for yourself how certain changes of the code will affect running speed?


When you are aiming for the first goal, your benchmark should run your code in a way as similar as possible to the "production" case - which normally means with memoization enabled, and with a ratio of "unmemoized-to-memoized" calls which reflects production usage. The benchmark will then show you the effect of the memoization.
However, you wrote

But The benchmark will normally run the code I've given it several times and compile statistics and averages on that code

Here you need to ask yourself whether that also happens in your real use cases as well, or not? Will the code be run in production several times, where the memoized values from the former runs will speed up later runs? Or is this a situation artificially created by your benchmark, but not reflecting what will really happen later under "productive conditions"? Your benchmark should take that into account, and repetitive runs inside the benchmark should start with a cleared memoization cache as often as you expect this to happen "in production".
In case your goal is just learning about the speed impact of certain code changes, then yes, memoization may mask that and you better switch it off for this purpose.
Maybe you are interested in both results - the behaviour with memoization, and the behaviour without, for the purpose of comparing them? Then design your program in a way you can switch memoization on and off at run time, and create two benchmarks. That could also make sense for measuring the increased memory usage by memoization.
So in short: clarify your goals - that is nothing we can really do for you.

All benchmarks have a goal of estimating production performance. The question is - how often production will repeat calls to benefit from caching? And how do we mimic that in a benchmark?

@Basilevs: programs dealing with aclic graphs  - that sounds a lot like scientific research for me, maybe computer science, maybe mathematics. And some scientist might be interested in speed improvements just for research purposes only. So just because you have trouble to imagine someone else does benchmarks not just for production purposes does not mean it could not be the case.

In scientific research the production is a scientific paper. The paper will describe how call count and other measurements were done. So my statement holds.

This program is indeed intended for scientific purposes, but “my research” isn't specifically about the quest for performance; it's actually a separate issue from my project, but one that I considered useful all the same.

@DocBrown: Thanks for clarifying my own question, I'll take these tips into account for future measurements.

As mentioned in another answer, JIT is a good example case of having to make these tradeoffs.  When accounting for Just In Time Compiling, which drastically speeds up many languages, it is often decided that the correct benchmark for people to interpret is the fully JIT'd case (fully memoized) because that is representative of how the software would actually run.  It's common to "warm up" such code so that it is properly memoized.  If you use that code in a different way (maybe calling it once), then the benchmark would be misleading and would need to be adapted.

@CortAmmon: in the described case, it sounds like it is probably the other way round here: a benchmark which because of running the tested code repeatedly (because one wants to get timing results in seconds, not small fractions of seconds) may "warm up" the memoization cache too much. But I am not sure, the question isn't really clear about this detail.

The first step should be to ensure you are benchmarking correctly. This include compensating for JIT-time, using representative data sets, measuring multiple runs, using different data sets etc. The closer you are to real world usage the better. You might want to use benchmark .net if you are not already, since this takes care of some pitfalls.
But it is not clear how long you keep the memoized data. If you keep adding data without clearing it, and without some kind of upper bound, you have a memory leak. So for a meaningful benchmark you might want to also measure memory usage, or to set an upper bound for how much memory can be used.
Next you probably want to validate the result. If you have a known good reference implementation this can be used for comparison, just write a automated test using a bunch of randomized inputs. If the results of your optimized solution matches that of your non optimized you can be reasonably confident in its result.

is benchmarking memoised code useful?

Absolutely! Benchmarking is essential for any kind of optimization.

Or how do you run a benchmark for such an optimisation?

It might require a bit more effort in creating representative benchmarks, but in principle it is no different from any other kind of optimization. Trading memory for CPU cycles is a very common optimization strategy.

From this, I can conclude either that my optimisation is perfect, or that my optimisation cheats on the benchmark. The order of magnitude between the two versions (memoized and non-memoized) is significant.

It is not that uncommon for optimizations to improve execution time by many orders of magnitude when doing algorithm development. Congratulations! But if your benchmark shows zero time, you might want to either increase the measurement resolution, or increase the size of the  data set.

because I want to measure the performance gain of an optimisation, but this optimisation is such that the more the code advances the faster the program becomes

It might be useful to plot the number of nodes processed per second against the number of nodes processed in total. This should give some idea of the kind of scaling you can expect. You might also want to plot the memory usage to see how this grows. Both should hopefully plateau eventually.
You could probably also calculate the expected benefit and memory usage of memoization, but this might be complicated and require statistical models of the input data.

Measuring memory usage is indeed a parameter I didn't consider but could be revealing, thanks for that! Thanks for your other useful tips.


is benchmarking memoised code useful?

Absolutely. For one, it's necessary if you want to confirm that your memoization is actually helping.
For example, computing 1 + 2 will be faster without memoizing it, because doing dict[1, 2] to look up the answer is slower than just recomputing it.
That's obviously an extreme case, but it's not uncommon for people to try to memoize things that don't really benefit from memoizing. This can happen if the argument to a memoized function are more diverse than expected, so there's fewer cache hits. In that case, you're doing a lot of book-keeping and memory stuff, just to cache values that will never be retrieved again.

You may be right about cheating yourself. Remember, memoization comes at a cost. You're making the classic time-space trade off. Yes it can be faster to find a result in memory than to calculate it. Right up until you don't have enough memory to avoid a cache miss. Make sure your benchmarking simulates realistic conditions.

Measuring memory usage is indeed a parameter I didn't consider but could be revealing, thanks for that!

It does not matter whether your code is memoized. What matters are target code execution time and preconditions.

If user can't notice the delay, do not measure the performance, .

Make sure the measurement is done with preconditions matching production. Reset memoization cache before each measurement.



Kinda, but you have to understand the performance model underlying your benchmark. Notably, in order to compare two benchmarks their models must be compatible.

The "classical" benchmark that resolves around taking an average of N executions time ultimately assumes each execution is independent. Notably, the number of executions only affects the expected accuracy of the result, not its expected value. This is a reasonable (if not entirely accurate) assumption for purely compute tasks.
Representing this with a single number* - the average execution time - is reasonable.
However, memoization is not a purely compute task: it is one compute-and store-task, and afterwards only reads. Averaging over these is bogus as the expected value of the result does change with the number of executions.
A reasonable benchmark model for memoization thus has to take the number of executions into account. This could be a function of execution count, it could be a pair of compute-and-store and read benchmarks. Notably, it’s not just one number!

How to benchmark this in practice depends on how well your code can be instrumented and how feature rich your benchmark framework is. If you can supply setup and teardown procedures for the benchmark, then you can get away with just three steps:

Benchmark the un-memoized code as-is.
Benchmark the compute-and-store of memoization. Teardown resets the memoization.
Benchmark the read of memoization. Setup is the initial compute-and-store, teardown resets the memoization.

These three benchmarks give you the information needed to compare the different approaches depending on the number of accesses. In the end, you have to decide for yourself which number or range of accesses is performance critical for your real life usecase.

*Plus accuracy of you want to be fancy.

So your code is faster, and your benchmark gives better results. That’s not cheating. That’s exactly what is supposed to happen.

This was my thought too. If you aren't expecting the cache to get hit, why memoize anything? It's faster with memoization? Mission accomplished. But still, is the real environment going to run under similar situations?

The question is whether the better (micro-)benchmark results are realistic.  If the whole-application real-world performance is obviously better then yes, good, it's a real speedup, not only in a benchmark with repetitive inputs and no other cache-footprint pressure.  But there's still a question of how to micro-benchmark if you want to tune even further than your first attempt at memoization.

Yes, memoization can skew benchmarks. Since memoization stores previous results to avoid recalculating, it can improve performance for repeated calls but may give misleading results in tests that focus on raw computation time, especially for unique or non-repetitive inputs. To get accurate benchmarks, you might need to disable memoization or reset the cache between tests.

I think this misses the point of adding memoization. The whole point is to improve performance. I would want to see both benchmarks: with and without memoization. Resetting the cache between tests might or might not give accurate results compared to what the code would perform like in a real production environment. The point of performance testing is to improve something "in the wild," not in a lab.
